# How to use the Total Probability Theorem help needed

Tags: probability

Hi I'm stuck on this question and don't know how to do it.

> Q. It has been observed that 30% of emails sent to your account is spam and as a result you have set up a spam filter. However the ﬁlter fails to quarantine 2% of spam emails and inadvertently quarantines 3% of genuine emails. What is the probability that an email will be quarantined as spam?
>
> Total Probability Theorem:  $$\mathsf P(A) = \mathsf P(A\mid B_1)\,\mathsf P(B_1)+\mathsf P(A\mid B_2)\,\mathsf P(B_2)$$

Comment: You'll get a better response if you show what you tried, explain your thoughts, and write the problem here directly.

Comment: There are two ways an e-mail can be quarantined: (i) It is spam and detected or (ii) it is not spam but is falsely accused.  The probability of (i) is $(0.3)(0.980$.  The probability of (ii) is $(0.7)(0.03)$.

Comment: Law of total probability: $P(Q) = P(Q \cap S) + P(Q \cap S^c).$
Gen'l mult rule: $P(Q \cap S) = P(S)P(Q|S) = ??$ Then $P(Q \cap S^c) = ??$

Comment: @AndreNichola Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Q. It has been observed that 30% of emails sent to your account is spam and as a result you have set up a spam filter. However the ﬁlter fails to quarantine 2% of spam emails and inadvertently quarantines 3% of genuine emails. What is the probability that an email will be quarantined as spam?

**Step 1:** Identify your knowns.

- Let $\mathsf P(S) = 0.30$ be the probability of spam.
- Let $\mathsf P(Q\mid S) = 0.02$ be the probability of quarantine given spam
- Let $\mathsf P(Q\mid \neg S)= 0.03$ be the probability of quarantine given not-spam.

**Step 2:** Identify what you want to know in terms of what you do know.  (Use the *law of total probability*)

- $\mathsf P(Q) = \ldots$